# Stop Qmail from sending an email to log

Tags: configuration, email-server, email

Every email we send is causing qmail to send an email to log@servername.domain.com

How do I disable this?

Thank you,
Chance

EDIT:

I created `/var/qmail/alias/.qmail-log` containing `|exit 0`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This performance is typically added by modifying the "extra.h"[1](http://cr.yp.to/qmail/faq/admin.html) file before compilation.

You can modify the dot-qmail[2](http://www.ezmlm.org/man/man5/dot-qmail.5.html) alias to send to null.  You could also recompile QMAIL without this patch.

```
~alias/.qmail-log
```

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!  I love QMAIL.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD, if I put the following in /var/qmail/alias/.qmail-log or /home/vpopmail/domains/[defaultdomain.com]/.qmail-log

```
| /dev/null
```

I will get this error message:

deferral: /dev/null:_Permission_denied/

in maillog
so for both files I use

```
| exit 0
```